# Tracing the word “form”

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview, terminology, multilinear-algebra

Today the word ***form*** can refer to (at least) three different kinds of mathematical object:

1. A homogeneous polynomial. This was apparently started by Gauss ([1801](https://archive.org/stream/werkecarlf01gausrich#page/n129)), renaming what others had called ***formulas***<sup>a</sup>. (See e.g. Bachmann [1922](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?48.1108.03), [p. 17](https://archive.org/stream/s2p1werkehrsgvon10gausuoft#page/n22).)
2. A scalar-valued linear or multilinear map. Apparently started by Kronecker ([1866](https://books.google.com/books?id=mxFLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA597)) / Weierstrass ([1868](https://books.google.com/books?id=qClJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA310)), rather out of the blue.
3. A field of forms in the sense 1 or 2. Apparently started by Christoffel ([1869](https://books.google.com/books?id=9D9bAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA56&q=%22lineare+Form%22#v=onepage)) / Lipschitz ([1869](https://books.google.com/books?id=9D9bAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA74&q=%22Formen+von%22#v=onepage)), renaming what others called differential ***formulas***<sup>b</sup> or ***expressions***<sup>c</sup>. (See e.g. Weitzenböck [1922](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?48.0517.01), [p. 29](https://archive.org/stream/encyklomath303encyrich#page/n654).)

> **Question:** Has anyone anywhere ever *discussed* these choices and switches in terminology?

$\ $

---

References: e.g.
<sup>a</sup>)
Euler ([1770](https://books.google.com/books?id=wB1aAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA379&dq=Formel), [1774](https://archive.org/stream/elemensdalgbre02eule#page/195), [1827](https://archive.org/stream/elementsofalgebr00eule#page/387)), Lagrange ([1773](https://archive.org/stream/uvresdelagrange03lagr#page/695), [1774](https://archive.org/stream/elemensdalgbre02eule#page/636)), Liouville ([1852](https://books.google.com/books?id=y5tbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA478)).
<sup>b</sup>)
Bernoulli ([1712](https://books.google.com/books?id=Db9eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP739&dq=formule)),
Euler ([1755](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_sYE_AAAAcAAJ#page/n229), [1768](https://archive.org/stream/institutionescal020326mbp#page/n297)),
Agnesi ([1775](https://books.google.com/books?id=XQ1bAAAAQAAJ&q=%22formule+diff%C3%A9rentielle%22)), Cousin ([1777](https://books.google.com/books?id=obF1teMTx6oC&pg=PA289&dq=%22formule+diff%C3%A9rentielle%22)),
Lagrange ([1786](https://archive.org/stream/mmoiresdelacadm04turigoog#page/n229)), Bossut ([1798](https://books.google.com/books?id=pro_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA127&dq=formule)), Poisson ([1811](https://books.google.com/books?id=zt2wKlNovI8C&pg=PA291&dq=formule)), Abel ([1826](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZppGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA185&dq=Differential+Formel)), Liouville ([1852](https://books.google.com/books?id=y5tbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA478), [1856](https://books.google.com/books?id=mMVDfrvRyb0C&pg=PA445&dq=%22formule+diff%C3%A9rentielle%22)).
<sup>c</sup>)
Gauss ([1815](https://archive.org/stream/werkecarlf03gausrich#page/n245)), Jacobi ([1845](https://books.google.com/books?id=EgVCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA240&dq=expressio+differentialis)), Riemann ([1867](https://books.google.com/books?id=P8qTb9q1T9QC&pg=PA8&dq=Differentialausdruck)), Sturm ([1877](https://books.google.com/books?id=N-I3AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=expression+diff%C3%A9rentielle)), Frobenius ([1879](https://books.google.com/books?id=85HxAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=Differentialausdruck)), Darboux ([1882](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMA_1882_2_6_1_14_1)), Cartan ([1899](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.467)).

Comment: On an $n$-dimensional vector space, a linear form $\varphi$ is the same thing as a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables  (indeterminates) of degree 1 once you express $\varphi$ in terms of a basis. Thus your second and third mathematical objects are closely related.

Comment: You can also think of forms of of an algebraic group (groups defined over the same field and isomorphic to it over some extension), or to (automorphic) form as particular elements in an automorphic representation.

Comment: @DesideriusSeverus it's not specific to algebraic groups, but to plenty of structures defined over a base ring or field (scheme, variety, algebra, vector space with a quadratic form, etc). Serre's book "Galois cohomology", Chap 3, starts with a paragraph "forms" in this general sense (albeit with no general definition). (quoth: *Let $K/k$ be a field extension, and $X$ an "object" defined over $k$. We say that a object $Y$, defined over $k$, is a $K/k$-form of $X$ it $Y$ becomes isomorphic to $X$ after extending scalars to $K$*)

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the update, I only use it and think of it in the algebraic group setting so I wasn't aware of this broader (and indeed quite natural) general notion ;)

Comment: @YCor title restored as I’m more after tracing these 3 uses than tallying others.

Comment: I'm happy with the new title as it makes it clear that it's about the use of the term "form" :) also I added the tag history on which clearly this question clearly belongs. I had to remove one, so chose quadratic-forms as it's covered by multilinear algebra.

Comment: Possibly "quadratic form" is a reinterpretation of phrases such as "numbers of the form $x^2+y^2$".

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies That’s for sure. Papers usually start with talk of things “of this form”, “of that form”, “in normal form”, and some authors using another word (Euler, Darboux) ostensibly do that to *keep* “form” available for such informal(!) talk.

Comment: Not to be confused with the question "Forming the word 'trace'."

Comment: Formally, "formula" is the diminutive form of "forma".

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn ...for which you could take a look at my question https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6603 ;)

Comment: Generalizing what KConrad says there is a natural relationship between homogeneous polynomials and symmetric multilinear forms.  I have aways assumed that was historical, but it's possible it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The evolution of the concept of a *form* from arithmetic to algebra is discussed on pp. 20, 21, 27 of F. Brechenmacher ([arXiv:0712.2566](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2566); revised version published in [2016](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3617469)):

> Whereas such terms as “forms” and “transformations” had been given an explicit mathematical definition in the arithmetic of quadratic forms in relation to the notion of equivalence relation that had been introduced by Gauss’ 1801 *Disquisitiones arithmeticae*, they pointed to various and mostly implicit meanings within the algebraic framework of the discussion. (...)
>
> Kronecker had been implicitly referring to the legacy of the works of Gauss and Hermite on the arithmetic of quadratic forms in [1866](https://books.google.com/books?id=mxFLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA597) — [when] he preferred to make use of the term “form” to name what others would designate as a function ([Weierstrass, [1858](https://books.google.com/books?id=V-Q6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA207)]) or as a “polynom” ([Jordan, [1873](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3034n/f1487)]) (...)
>
> Kronecker blamed algebraic methods [notably by Jordan] for their tendency to think in term of the “general” case with little attention given to the arithmetic difficulties that might be caused by assigning specific values to the symbols (...) [He] appealed to the tradition of Gauss on behalf of his claim that the theory of forms should be considered as belonging to arithmetic and should consequently focus on the characterisation of equivalence classes in establishing arithmetical invariants thanks to some effective procedures such as *g.c.d*.s computations.

Comment: Thank you. (Your text seems to differ significantly from both the arXiv and the published version?!)

Comment: indeed, this is not a literal quote but my attempt to summarize several pages of text into something that would be appropriate for the MO answer box; I have removed the "quote" formatting to avoid suggesting that this is quoted verbatim.

Comment: The quote (now literal) nicely explains Kronecker’s motives — but he must have been “blaming” *someone else* in 1866, before Jordan appeared. Elsewhere Brechenmacher ([2007, footnote 3](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2449506)) describes Jordan’s [1874 switch to “form”](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?06.0070.0*) as almost political; I wonder why he (and [Jahrbuch](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?068.1774cj), [Kronecker](https://archive.org/stream/werkehrsgaufvera01kronuoft#page/145)) keep misquoting Christoffel’s 1868 *Theorie der bilinearen Functionen* as *bilinearen* ***Formen***?